# Identifying index of list of lists

Tags: list, loops, for-loop, iteration, infinite-loop

Hey I have a list containing four lists and I would like to iterate over the entire thing and print the index for all occurrences of a specific number or variable. So for example I have:

```
list_of_lists = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,2,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]

lx = 0
for x in list_of_lists:
    ly = 0
    for a in x:
        if a == 2:
            print(lx,ly)
        ly += 1
    lx += 1
```

Now this does print "2 1" which is correct but rather than print once, it prints infinitely. I'm not sure what is wrong with my logic but I'm pretty sure I am making a simple error. I am new to programming as you may be able to tell. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you did anything wrong here. I tried your code and mine runs only once, are you sure your indentations are ok in your original code?

Comment: Ah okay I'm realizing the problem is that I have all of this inside of a while loop that is rerunning this chunk infinitely. I should have tested this block separately. Thanks for taking the time.